# How to catch event: re-initialise search in Algolia Instantsearch?

Tags: javascript, algolia, instantsearch, vue-instant-search

I am using Algolia and the Instantsearch library in a Vue project, to search for items. The user has the option to check each item (with a simple checkbox). Checking at least one item makes a toolbar visible, with a selection of actions to be applied on the selected batch of items in the search results.
When an search result item is checked, it fires a Vue method that pushes the item to a Vuex array called "selectedItems".
In order not to lose this selection with pagination, I have gone for the infinite hits widget. Thus all results remain on the same page.
Until here things work fine.
My problem is that when the user clicks on the cross in the searchbox to reinitialise the search, then the items are not checked anymore, but obviously they remain within the "selectedItems" array in Vuex.
How can I capture the event of the search re-initialising? If I can catch this event, I can then empty the "selectedItems" array so that it remains in sync with the search results.
I have only found this resource that presents events like click, conversion, view: https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/going-further/send-insights-events/js/
But nothing about other events like re-initialize search.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: somethng like this? https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/clear-refinements/vue/

Comment: @cmgchess Thanks but in my understanding this only clears Algolia refinements / filters. The checkbox I have in front of each result row is completely separated from Algolia. It is a local Vue way of storing the results that the user has checked. This is why I need a way to catch the "clear search query event" so that I can at the same time clear this local Vue array of results.